# Dart - Update List items including condition

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to change the items of a list whose variable `seen` is false,

my model:

```
class Message{
  String text;
  bool seen;
  Message(this.text, this.seen)
}
```

my list:

```
List<Message> messages = [

Message('hi', false),
Message('hi2', true),
Message('hi4', false),
Message('hi6', false),
Message('hi8', true),

];
```

Comment: Please add more context and code to what you want to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the items of the `messages` list whose `seen` variable is `false`, you can iterate through the list and use a conditional statement to check if the seen variable is `false`. If it is `false`, you can modify as you need.

Here's an example code snippet to achieve this:

```
for (var message in messages.where((element) => element.seen == false)) {
  message.seen = true;
}
```